# How do I make multiple drop-down list in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a multi-level drop-down list and I got everything made in html but it seems when I go into CSS all the levels are connected to the same .dropdown. Does anyone know how I can link my different drop-down lists to their own CSS .dropdown instead of it all being linked to the same one? Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open+Sans", sans-serif;
 }

 .navbar {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0C133C;
 }
 
 
 #nav {
     background-color: #fff; 
     color: white;
     width: 100%;
 
 }
 .nav {
   float: right;
     text-align: left;
   margin: 0;
 }
 .nav > li {                                                             
     display:Inline-block;
     padding: 20px 50px 10px 9px;                              
 }
 
.nav > li a {                                               
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0C133C;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;

}
.clearer {
    clear:both;
}

.subnav class{
  margin: 0;
position:relative;
}

 .subnav > div a {                                               
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #0C133C;
     font-size: 18px;
padding: 20px 30px 10px 9px;
}
  
.logo {
margin-top: 1rem;
}

.subnav {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
margin-right: 1rem; 

}

.split {
  height: 70%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -50;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}


.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #282C41;
color: white;
margin-top: .5rem;
 font-size: 15px;
}

 
.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
margin-top: .5rem;
font-size: 18px;
}


.dropbtn {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 10px ;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
    left: 175px; 
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #868686;}


-------Dropdown 2------

.dropbtn 2 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 10px ;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.dropdown 2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
    left: 175px; 

}

.dropdown-content 2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a 2 {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #868686;}

------Dropdown 3 ----

.dropbtn 3 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 10px ;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.dropdown 3 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
    left: 175px; 

}

.dropdown-content 3 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a 3 {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #868686;}

------Dropdown 4-----

.dropbtn 4 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 10px ;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.dropdown 4 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
    left: 175px; 

}

.dropdown-content 4 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a 4{
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #868686;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"
    

</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </div>
        

<subnav class="subnav subnav-light bg-light">
<img src="universallogo.jpg" class="logo"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="subnav=brand" href="#">
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Bonds</a>
</a>
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Report a Claim</a>
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About Us</a>
<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Search</a>
</div>
</subnav>
 

<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">
    <h1>GET YOUR LICENSE & PERMIT BONDS FAST & EASY</h1>
    <p>We provide our Customers with a fast, easy, and secure way to get bonded. Get your Free Quote in minutes.
</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Select Your State</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">California</a>
    <a href="#">Illinois</a>
    <a href="#">Michigan</a>
       <a href="#">Ohio</a>


</div>

<div class="dropdown2">
  <button class="dropbtn">Who is requring the bond</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Who is requring the bond</a>
    
</div>

<div class="dropdown3">
  <button class="dropbtn">What jurisdiction is requring the bond</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">What jurisdiction is requring the bond</a>
    </div>

<div class="dropdown3">
  <button class="dropbtn">Select Your Bond</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Select Your Bond</a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multilevel Dropdown Menu

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #1bc2a2;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #1bc2a2;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #2c3e50;
}

li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
  float: none;
}

li:hover a {
  background: #1bc2a2;
}

li:hover li a:hover {
  background: #2c3e50;
}

.main-navigation li ul li {
  border-top: 0;
}

ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

ul:before,
ul:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}

ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Front End Design</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Resets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grids</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frameworks</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Ajax</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```